# Как написать тест по scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

есть такой scope

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :city

  scope :get_all_items_in_city, ->(city) { where(city: city) }
end
```

по нему мне нужно сделать тест используя rspec-rails и factory_bot

есть такой набросок

```
RSpec.describe Item, type: :model do
  describe ".get_all_items_in_city" do

    let(:city) {'test'}
    it 'should gets all items in city' do

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
RSpec.describe Item, type: :model do
  describe ".get_all_items_in_city" do
    subject { described_class.get_all_items_in_city(city) }
    let(:city) { 'New York' }
    let!(:expected_cities) { create_list(:item, 2, city: city) }
    let!(:unexpected_cities) { create(:item, city: 'Random City') }
    
    it 'should return correct count of items' do
      expect(subject.count).to eq(2)
    end

    it 'should return correctlist of items' do
      expect(subject.to_a).to match_array(expected_cities)
    end
  end
end
```